# How can I store ArrayList data to mysql in single field?

Tags: java, mysql, collections, arraylist

I am having some data in ArrayList form.
I need to store it in MySQL in a single field.
How can i be doing it ?
Java defines List in order to store multiple data.
So is there any way by which I can go better that List?

Comment: if you are asking for a dataype for storing then mysql does not have

Comment: Why in the world would you want to store an array of objects in one field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the objects in the ArrayList are serialisable, you can serialise the ArrayList. There are a variety of formats, such as JSON.